# sql to find row for min date in each month

Tags: sql, postgresql, min

I have a table, lets say "Records" with structure:

```
id      date
--      ----
1       2012-08-30
2       2012-08-29
3       2012-07-25
```

I need to write an SQL query in PostgreSQL to get record_id for MIN date in each month.

```
month    record_id
-----    ---------
8           2
7           3
```

as we see 2012-08-29 < 2012-08-30 and it is 8 month, so we should show record_id = 2

I tried something like this,

```
SELECT
   EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) as month,
   record_id,
   MIN(date) 
FROM Records
GROUP BY 1,2
```

but it shows 3 records.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return multiples if you have duplicate minimum dates:

```
Select
  minbymonth.Month,
  r.record_id
From (
  Select
    Extract(Month From date) As Month, 
    Min(date) As Date
  From
    records
  Group By 
    Extract(Month From date)
  ) minbymonth
    Inner Join
  records r
    On minbymonth.date = r.date
Order By
  1;
```

Or if you have CTEs

```
With MinByMonth As (
  Select
    Extract(Month From date) As Month, 
    Min(date) As Date
  From
    records
  Group By 
    Extract(Month From date)
  )
Select
  m.Month,
  r.record_id
From
  MinByMonth m
    Inner Join
  Records r
    On m.date = r.date
Order By
  1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/2a054/3

Comment: That clearly is the way to go. For clarity, I would have placed the subquery as a CTE ( like `WITH minbymonth AS ( ... your query ... ) SELECT`. Thats just a matter of taste, though. +1

Comment: @Thilo Good call, added this too.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date))
   id,
   date
FROM Records1
ORDER BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date),date
```

SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/76ca2/3

UPD: This query:

1) Orders the records by month and date

2) For every month picks the first record (the first record has `MIN(date)` because of ordering)

Details here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT

Comment: Hmm. But how do you select the MIN date in each month?

Comment: @Kirill Reva Fixed the query

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/2bb2a/9)

```
select distinct on (date_trunc('month', date))
    date_trunc('month', date) as month,
    id,
    date
from records
order by 1, 3 desc
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select extract(month from date) 
, record_id
, date
from
(
    select
        record_id
       , date
       , rank() over (partition by extract(month from date) order by date asc) r
    from records
) x
where r=1
order by date
```

Comment: ps. change `rank()` to `row_number()` if you want a single result when there are duplicate minimum dates in a given month.  Alternatively change `order by date asc` to `order by date asc, order by record_id asc` to get the record with the lower id when you have duplicate min dates.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need use sub-query, something like this:

```
SELECT
   EXTRACT(MONTH FROM r.date) as month,
   r.record_id 
FROM Records as r
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
       EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) as month,
       MIN(date) as mindate
    FROM Records
    GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date)
) as sub on EXTRACT(MONTH FROM r.date) = sub.month and r.date = sub.mindate
```

Answer (score 0):

Following works for me in t-sql:

```sql
SELECT
  MIN([date])
FROM
  Records
GROUP BY
  FORMAT([date], 'yyyy-MM')
ORDER BY
  FORMAT([date], 'yyyy-MM') DESC
```